A particular subgroup of $SL(2,C)$
Let $T$ be the subgroup of diagonal matrices of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ and $S^1$ be the subgroup of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ given by the identifications and inclusions $S^1 \cong SO(2,\mathbb{R}) \hookrightarrow SL(2, \mathbb{R}) \hookrightarrow SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, that is, the subgroup of the form
$$
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a
\end{pmatrix} \mid a, \, b \in \mathbb{R}, \, a^2 + b^2 = 1
\right\}.
$$
What is the subgroup $G$ of $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ generated by these two subgroups? Is it the whole $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$?
Taking $a=0$ and $b=1$, we have the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$, and so $G$ includes the normaliser of $T$, but I wasn't able to go much further than this.

The Lie algebras generate $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbf{C})$ as real Lie algebra, so the group generated by these two subgroups should be all of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C})$. A direct proof should be doable but with the cost of more computations.
